# Как не обновлять страницу при нажатии на input[type=submit]?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

У меня имеется `index.php`, а в нём `php+html` код. Имеется кнопка, при нажатии на которую, происходит обработка `php` кода, и страница обновляется.
Как сделать чтобы страница не обновлялась при нажатии на кнопку? Пример кода:

```
<input class="col-xs-12 btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Показать"/> - кнопка


if(isset($_POST['enter'])
{ //тут код }
```

Comment: php здесь ни при чем

Comment: @Alex как не причем если у него файл index.php ?

Comment: @Даниил потому что проблема не в php, а в понимании работы `submit`(html) и ajax (jquery)

Comment: @Alex тогда уж весь вопрос поправьте.

Comment: @Alex а так как вопрос такой какой есть, метка PHP уместна по нескольким причинам, например файлы с расширением .php. В вопросе есть код PHP. И в самом заголовке автор написал что работает с PHP

Comment: @Даниил посмотрите пожалуйста внимательно принятый ответ

Comment: вопрос в принципе про то **как не обновлять**, а не **как обрабатывать** ) а для этого просто `submit` замените на `button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> index.php

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input class="col-xs-12 btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Показать"/>  
</form>
```

> script.js

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "post.php",   
      datatype: "text",
      data: {enter : $("#enter").val() },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
});
```

> post.php

```
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){ 
 echo "Post data: ".$_POST['enter']; //тут код 
}
```